Asking for input until its valid
i got this code where i try to help the teacher to calculate the grades of the students bases on given tasks :
#include <stdio.h>

#define PASS 55
#define MAX_NUM_OF_STUDENTS 10
#define NUM_OF_TASKS 4

int main() {
    int i, j, num_of_students, grade;
    float highestGrade = 0, lowestGrade = 100, passedCount = 0;
    float taskPercentages[NUM_OF_TASKS] = {0}; // Array to store task percentages
    float totalGrades[MAX_NUM_OF_STUDENTS] = {0}; // Array to store total grades

    printf("Welcome to our grading system!\n");

    // Take the percentage of each task and check for invalid input.
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_TASKS; i++) {
        while (1) {
            printf("Please enter the percentage of task %d:\n", i + 1);
            if (scanf("%f", &taskPercentages[i]) != 1) {
                printf("Input Error\n");
            } else if (taskPercentages[i] < 0 || taskPercentages[i] > 1) {
                printf("Maximum percentage is 1 and minimum percentage is 0. Please try again!\n");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Calculate the sum of task percentages.
    float sumWeight = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_TASKS; i++) {
        sumWeight += taskPercentages[i];
    }

    // Ensure the sum weight of the tasks is exactly 1.
    if (sumWeight != 1.0) {
        printf("The sum weight of the tasks is %.2f and it should be 1. Please try again!\n", sumWeight);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("How many students in your class?\n");
    while (1) {
        if (scanf("%d", &num_of_students) != 1) {
            printf("Input Error\n");
        } else if (num_of_students < 1 || num_of_students > MAX_NUM_OF_STUDENTS) {
            printf("Maximum number of students in a course is %d and minimum 1. Please try again!\n", MAX_NUM_OF_STUDENTS);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Get students' grades and calculate the total grade.
    for (i = 0; i < num_of_students; i++) {
        totalGrades[i] = 0.0;
        printf("Please enter student %d grades.\n", i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_OF_TASKS; j++) {
            while (1) {
                printf("Enter grade %d:\n", j + 1);
                if (scanf("%d", &grade) != 1) {
                    printf("Input Error\n");
                } else if (grade < 0 || grade > 100) {
                    printf("Maximum grade is 100, minimum grade is 0. Please try again!\n");
                } else {
                    totalGrades[i] += grade * taskPercentages[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (totalGrades[i] > highestGrade) highestGrade = totalGrades[i];
        if (totalGrades[i] < lowestGrade) lowestGrade = totalGrades[i];
        if (totalGrades[i] >= PASS) passedCount++;
    }

    float sumGrades = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < num_of_students; i++) {
        sumGrades += totalGrades[i];
    }
    float averageGrade = sumGrades / num_of_students;

    printf("Number of students: %d\n", num_of_students);
    printf("Percentage of each task:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_TASKS; i++) {
        printf("Task %d: %.2f\n", i + 1, taskPercentages[i]);
    }
    printf("\nThe grades are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num_of_students; i++) {
        printf("Student %d: %.2f\n", i + 1, totalGrades[i]);
    }
    printf("\nHighest grade: %.2f\n", highestGrade);
    printf("Lowest grade: %.2f\n", lowestGrade);
    printf("Average: %.2f\n", averageGrade);
    printf("Number of passing students: %.0f\n", passedCount);
    printf("Thank you for using our system!\n");

    return 0;
}

the output i am supposed to get in this specific input :
0.5 0 0 0.6 -1 v

is :
Welcome to our grading system!
Please enter the percentage of task 1:
Please enter the percentage of task 2:
Please enter the percentage of task 3:
Please enter the percentage of task 4:
The sum weight of the tasks is 1.10 and it should be 1. Please try again!
Please enter the percentage of task 1:
Maximum percentage is 1 and minimum percentage is 0. Please try again!
Input Error!

but my output is coming as :
Welcome to our grading system!
Please enter the percentage of task 1:
Please enter the percentage of task 2:
Please enter the percentage of task 3:
Please enter the percentage of task 4:
The sum weight of the tasks is 1.10 and it should be 1. Please try again!

my output dosen't allow the user to give new input , whenever i try to fix it and combine them in the same loop i get runtime error .
any recommendations ?

In main(): if (sumWeight != 1.0) {         printf("The sum weight of the tasks is %.2f and it should be 1. Please try again!\n", sumWeight);         return 1;     } That return 1; is an exit from the program. If you want to loop back on error, you need a loop with the proper exit condition around the proper section of code. (or conditional break; in the loop)
